# PyTorch - RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CPU but got backend CUDA for argument #2 'weight'

Tags: neural-network, deep-learning, conv-neural-network, pytorch, torch

I load my previously trained model and want to classify a single (test) image from the disk through this model. All the operations in my model are carried out on my GPU. Hence, I move the `numpy array` of the test image to GPU by calling `cuda()` function. When I call the `forward()` function of my model with the `numpy array` of the test image, I get the `RuntimeError: Expected object of backend CPU but got backend CUDA for argument #2 'weight'`.

Here is the code I use to load the image from disk and call the `forward()` function:

```
test_img = imageio.imread('C:\\Users\\talha\\Desktop\\dog.png')
test_img = imresize(test_img, (28, 28))
test_tensor = torch.from_numpy(test_img)
test_tensor = test_tensor.cuda()
test_tensor = test_tensor.type(torch.FloatTensor)
log_results = model.forward(test_tensor)
```

**Software Environment:**

torch: `1.0.1`

GPU: `Nvidia GeForce GTX 1070`

OS: `Windows 10 64-bit`

Python: `3.7.1`

Comment: Do`model.cuda()` to make sure the model is on GPU. It seems the model is no GPU

Comment: No, it did not work. @UmangGupta

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Convert to `FloatTensor` before sending it over the GPU.

So, the order of operations will be:

```
test_tensor = torch.from_numpy(test_img)

# Convert to FloatTensor first
test_tensor = test_tensor.type(torch.FloatTensor)

# Then call cuda() on test_tensor
test_tensor = test_tensor.cuda()

log_results = model.forward(test_tensor)
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution. Could you please explain why is that order is critical?

Comment: I'm not really sure but I suspect that is because all the type conversion operations (`FloatTensor` in this case) happen on the CPU. Therefore, the tensor is brought back to the CPU for conversion.

Comment: Okay. I have a better understanding of tensor types now. Your data needs to be an instance of `torch.cuda.FloatTensor`, to be trained on a GPU. When you write  `test_tensor.type(torch.FloatTensor)`, the tensor gets converted to `torch.FloatTensor`, which becomes incompatible with a model on the GPU. So, in addition to the method above, you can also do it by changing `test_tensor.type(torch.FloatTensor)` to `test_tensor.type(torch.cuda.FloatTensor)`.